# Which form is 切り?

Tags: grammar, て-form, honorifics, renyōkei

On a Japanese package I've found this inscription:

> ここからお**切り**下さい。

This obviously means: "Please cut here (to open)". With my very basic knowledge of Japanese I would instead of お切り (お being the honorific prefix? Which can also be used for verbs?) have expected the て form, i.e. 切って下さい.
Why does it read お切り下さい instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

お + [masu-stem] + ください is *keigo* (honorific speech) for [te-form] + ください.

This rule works for verbs, which don't have a separate *keigo* verb, e.g. 切る

> お切りください

If the verb *does* have a separate *keigo* form, the formation is different:

> <s>お見ください</s> → ご覧ください
>   <s>お言いください</s> → おっしゃってください
>   <s>お行きください</s> → いらしてください
>   <s>お来ください</s> → おこしください

Comment: This answer is better than mine, but I'd like to point out that many people consider お召し上がりください an error. According to them, the proper form is 召し上がってください.

Comment: @Nothingatall Thank you for your comment. Yes, 二重敬語... Maybe I should remove this example. (More questions about 二重敬語 ("double _keigo_") (especially [this question](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12675)) can be found via http://japanese.stackexchange.com/search.)

Comment: People who mind お召し上がりください are minority.